# Converting string date to utc epoch in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, epoch

I have a UTC time as string, I want to convert it to UTC timestamp. But following code seems to again convert it to UTC causing it to be wrong timestap. How do I convert that datetime format to timestamp so that it preserves it as UTC.

```
datetime.strptime('2023-08-02 14:52:05', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp() * 1000

Input time GMT: 2023-08-02 14:52:05  
Outputs GMT: 1691002325000.0     
# This converts to GMT: Wednesday, August 2, 2023 6:52:05 PM https://www.epochconverter.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Use

```py
datetime.fromisoformat(f"{utc_time_string}+00:00").timestamp() * 1000
```

---

Your observation about the error is correct. [And that's because](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> **Naive [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) instances are assumed to represent local time** and this method relies on the platform C `mktime()` function to perform the conversion.

The docs also show how to get the timestamp from a naive datetime object which represents UTC:

> ```py
> timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
> ```

So you could do it as:

```py
(
    datetime
        .strptime('2023-08-02 14:52:05', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        .replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
        .timestamp() * 1000
)
```

Outputs `1690987925000.0` which is `GMT: Wednesday, August 2, 2023 2:52:05 PM`

Since you appear to have an almost-ISO datetime string, you could also use [`.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) and affix add "+00:00" at the end of the string before the conversion. That generates a TZ-aware datetime object and `.timestamp()` handles that properly:

```py
utc_time_string = '2023-08-02 14:52:05'
(
    datetime
        .fromisoformat(f"{utc_time_string}+00:00")
        .timestamp() * 1000
)
# fits nicely on one line
datetime.fromisoformat(f"{utc_time_string}+00:00").timestamp() * 1000
```

Also outputs `1690987925000.0`.

For [Python 3.11 onwards, you can add the suffix "Z"](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) instead of "+00:00".

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `datetime.fromtimestamp` function to convert from a timestamp back to a `datetime.datetime` object.

Here is the code:

```
date_timestamp = datetime.strptime('2023-08-02 14:52:05', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp()
date_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(date_timestamp)
```

If you end up multiplying a timestamp by 1000, then you will end up getting an error since `1691002325000.0` is not a valid timestamp.

Comment: Adding milliseconds is done by adding a decimal to the number
ex.
timestamp      = datetime
1691013125.5 = 2023-08-02 14:52:05.500000
1691013125    = 2023-08-02 14:52:05

The difference here is 500 milliseconds which is a 0.5 difference between the two timestamps.